Adjusting the wrapped alignment of beamer table of contents
I want to have bullet points for my table of contents, so I added the following lines to beamer file:
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\vspace*{1em}\textcolor{lightgray}{$\blacktriangleright$}\hspace{0.5em}\inserttocsection \\}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace{1em}\textcolor{lightgray}{$\bullet$}\hspace{0.5em}\small\inserttocsubsection \\}

This looks good for titles that fit within the space, but for titles that are too long, the wrapping doesn't line up because of the manual spacing I add around the bullet points.
How can I adjust the spacing around the bullet points and also have the wrapped text line up as desired?
Example document:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, handout]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\vspace*{1em}\textcolor{lightgray}{$\blacktriangleright$}\hspace{0.5em}\inserttocsection \\}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace{1em}\textcolor{lightgray}{$\bullet$}\hspace{0.5em}\small\inserttocsubsection \\}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.05\textwidth}
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents[sections={-2}]
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents[sections={3-}]
    \column{0.05\textwidth}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2 title that is way too long so it wraps around}
\subsection{Subsection 5}
\subsection{Subsection 6}
\subsection{Subsection 7}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 8}
\subsection{Subsection 9 title that is way too long so it wraps around}
\subsection{Subsection 10}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

The resulting table of contents:

To clarify, for the section and subsection titles I want the words "so" and "long" to be lined up with "Section" and "Subsection", respectively.

\documentclass[aspectratio=169, handout]{beamer}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}
{\bigskip\leavevmode\leftskip=2ex%
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section number projected}%
    \raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}\hskip1ex}%
  \inserttocsection\par}    

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=5ex\llap{%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection number projected}%
    \raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\bullet$}\hskip1ex}\inserttocsubsection\par}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{fg=lightgray}
\setbeamercolor{subsection number projected}{fg=lightgray}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{columns}[totalwidth=.8\textwidth]
  \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents[sections={-2}]
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents[sections={3-}]
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2 title that is way too long so it wraps around}
\subsection{Subsection 5}
\subsection{Subsection 6}
\subsection{Subsection 7}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 8}
\subsection{Subsection 9 title that is way too long so it wraps around}
\subsection{Subsection 10}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



This works well. I've accepted your answer, but if you get a chance, can you explain how this works? I'd like to understand the code in case I want to use some of these techniques for something else in the future.
